# Multiple criteria lookup in R

Tags: r

I have data like this:

```
ID        1a      2a      3a      1b      2b      3b      Name      Team
cb128c   James   John    Bill    Jeremy   Ed     Simon    Simon     Wolves
cb128c   John    James   Randy   Simon    David  Ben      John      Tigers
ko351u   Adam    Alex    Jacob   Bob      Oscar  David    Oscar     Sparrows
ko351u   Adam    Matt    Sam     Fred     Frank  Harry    Adam      Wildcats
```

And I want to add columns indicating teams A and B by matching the row ID of that row in the ID column, and by matching one of the names in one of the "a" columns of that row in the "Name" column (for Team A), and doing the same for Team B using one of the names in one of the "b" columns of that row:

```
ID        1a      2a      3a      1b      2b      3b      Name      Team     Team A    Team B
cb128c   James   John    Bill    Jeremy   Ed     Simon    Simon     Wolves   Tigers    Wolves
cb128c   John    James   Randy   Simon    David  Ben      John      Tigers   Tigers    Wolves
ko351u   Adam    Alex    Jacob   Bob      Oscar  David    Oscar     Sparrows Wildcats  Sparrows
ko351u   Adam    Matt    Sam     Fred     Frank  Harry    Adam      Wildcats Wildcats  Sparrows
```

In row 1, we know Team A is Tigers because we match the ID of row 1, cb128c, in the ID column, and one of the "a" names of row 1 (either James, John or Bill) in the Name column. In this case, Row 2 has that ID, cb128c, and has "John" in the Name column. The Team in row 2 is "Tigers." Therefore, Row 1's Team A is Tigers. Team B is the Wolves because we match row 1's ID, still cb128c, and one of the "b" names in row 1 (either Jeremy, Ed or Simon) in the Name column. In this case, row 1 itself has the data we're looking for since one of the "b" names appears in the "Name" column of that row (Simon). The "Team" listed in each row will always either be the Team A or the Team B for that row.

Further down, we know Team A for row 3 is Wildcats because we match row 3's ID, ko351u and one of row 3's "a" names (either Adam, Alex or Jacob) in the "Name" column. Row 4 has that ID and "Adam" in the Name column. So the Team in Row 4 is Team A for Row 3.

Also notice that David switched teams in Row 3. In Row 2, David was on Simon's team, which we know is the Wolves (as explained above), but when we match Row 3's ID and one of Row 3's "b" names (Bob, Oscar or David), we get the Sparrows (like Row 1, one of the "b" names appears in the name column of that same row, so the Team B is the Team listed in that row).

How can I get this done in R?

Comment: Your example input doesn't have any "Sparrows", but your output does. Is this just a typo?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a typo... I just corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = read.table(text = "ID        1a      2a      3a      1b      2b      3b      Name      Team
cb128c   James   John    Bill    Jeremy   Ed     Simon    Simon     Wolves
cb128c   John    James   Randy   Simon    David  Ben      John      Tigers
ko351u   Adam    Alex    Jacob   Bob      Oscar  David    Oscar     Sparrows
ko351u   Adam    Matt    Sam     Fred     Frank  Harry    Adam      Wildcats", header = T)

# convert to character
df[] = lapply(df, as.character)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
```

The following code 1. gathers to long format, 2. creates "Team_A" and "Team_B" out of the a or b suffix, 3. matches names to fill in the A/B Team Name, 4. removes missing values (no match), 5. gets rid of unnecessary columns, 6. converts back to wide format, 7. joins the A and B teams to the original data.

I'd encourage you to step through the code line by line to understand what's going on. I'll leave reordering the columns to you.

```
result = gather(df, key = "key", value = "value", starts_with("X")) %>%
    mutate(ab = paste0("Team_", toupper(substr(key, start = nchar(key), stop = nchar(key)))), 
           team = ifelse(Name == value, Team, NA)) %>%
    filter(!is.na(team)) %>%
    select(ID, ab, team) %>%
    spread(key = ab, value = team) %>%
    right_join(df)


result
#       ID   Team_A   Team_B   X1a   X2a   X3a    X1b   X2b   X3b  Name     Team
# 1 cb128c   Tigers   Wolves James  John  Bill Jeremy    Ed Simon Simon   Wolves
# 2 cb128c   Tigers   Wolves  John James Randy  Simon David   Ben  John   Tigers
# 3 ko351u Wildcats Sparrows  Adam  Alex Jacob    Bob Oscar David Oscar Sparrows
# 4 ko351u Wildcats Sparrows  Adam  Matt   Sam   Fred Frank Harry  Adam Wildcats
```

Comment: I ran this line by line and am getting stuck when we get to the `spread` function. I get the error:

Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (followed by a list of rows).

I tried adding `unique()` in between the select and spread statements, but I get the same error with the problem rows listed in pairs in parentheses.

Comment: My problem was actually solved by adding `unique()`. It didn't work the first time I tried it because of a glitch in my data that incorrectly listed players in the "name" category that did not correspond to the listed team, therefore causing multiple instances of Team_A or Team_B appearing with the same ID. When I filtered those rows out and added `unique()`, it worked. Thanks for your help!